# FlowDocument XamlWriter Save - doesn't preserve tab

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, whitespace, flowdocument

I am using `XamlWriter.Save` and `XamlReader.Load` to serialize and deserialize a FlowDocument to a byte array to store it:

```
private static byte[] FlowDocumentToByteArray(FlowDocument flowDocument)
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        XamlWriter.Save(flowDocument, stream);
        stream.Position = 0;
        return stream.ToArray();
    }
}

private static FlowDocument FlowDocumentFromByteArray(byte[] bytes)
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
    {
        return (FlowDocument)XamlReader.Load(stream);
    }
}
```

However I'm having trouble with whitespace preservation.  The following test fails:

```
[TestMethod]
public void FlowDocumentTabsNoBackground()
{
    var flowDocument = new FlowDocument();

    var paragraph = new Paragraph();
    paragraph.Inlines.Add(new Run("\t"));
    paragraph.Inlines.Add(new Run("a"));
    flowDocument.Blocks.Add(paragraph);

    byte[] bytes = FlowDocumentToByteArray(flowDocument);

    FlowDocument flowDocumentOut = FlowDocumentFromByteArray(bytes);

    var textRange = new TextRange(flowDocumentOut.ContentStart, 
        flowDocumentOut.ContentEnd);
    Assert.IsTrue(textRange.Text.StartsWith("\t"));
}
```

But this test passes:

```
[TestMethod]
public void FlowDocumentTabsWithBackground()
{
    var flowDocument = new FlowDocument();

    var paragraph = new Paragraph();
    paragraph.Inlines.Add(new Run("\t"));
    paragraph.Inlines.Add(new Run("a")
        {
            Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255))
        }
    );
    flowDocument.Blocks.Add(paragraph);

    byte[] bytes = FlowDocumentToByteArray(flowDocument);

    FlowDocument flowDocumentOut = FlowDocumentFromByteArray(bytes);

    var textRange = new TextRange(flowDocumentOut.ContentStart, 
        flowDocumentOut.ContentEnd);
    Assert.IsTrue(textRange.Text.StartsWith("\t"));
}
```

Why doesn't the tab make it through the serialze/deserialize cycle and why does adding a background colour to one of the runs in a paragraph help?